# Ubuntu CloudFormation AutoScale

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I have a problem with Aws cfn on Ubuntu. My template is below. I tried many things, and still, I couldn't solve. I tried cfn on a single ec2 instance and it 's working. Thanks for your help.

When I logged in Instances, I have errors as follows.

```
/var/log/cloud-init.log:877:cloudinit.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
/var/log/cloud-init.log:898:RuntimeError: Runparts: 1 failures in 1 attempted commands
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log:626:ValidationError: Resource LaunchConfig is of type AWS_AS_LC_V3 and cannot be signaled
/var/log/cfn-wire.log:3:2020-05-10 20:02:15,389 [DEBUG] Response error: {"Error":{"Code":"ValidationError","Message":"Resource LaunchConfig is of type AWS_AS_LC_V3 and cannot be signaled","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"e45594a6-8fac-41a8-9ece-c3eaef3b0e18"}
```

**Template:**

```
Resources:
  WebServerGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    Properties:
      VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref Subnets
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref LaunchConfig
      MinSize: '2'
      MaxSize: '2'
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !Ref ALBTargetGroup
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT15M
        Count: '2'
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        MinInstancesInService: '1'
        MaxBatchSize: '1'
        PauseTime: PT15M
        WaitOnResourceSignals: 'true'
  LaunchConfig:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Install a simple application
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
        configSets:
          setup:
            - "configure_cfn"
        configure_cfn:
          files:
            /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [main]
                stack=${AWS::StackId}
                region=${AWS::Region}
                verbose=true
                interval=5
              mode: "000400"
              owner: root
              group: root
            /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
              content: !Sub |
                [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                triggers=post.update
                path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --configsets setup --region ${AWS::Region}
              mode: "000400"
              owner: root
              group: root
            /lib/systemd/system/cfn-hup.service:
              content: !Sub |
                [Unit]
                Description=cfn-hup daemon

                [Service]
                Type=simple
                ExecStart=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup
                Restart=always

                [Install]
                WantedBy=multi-user.target
              mode: "000400"
              owner: root
              group: root

    Properties:
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: !FindInMap 
        - AWSRegionArch2AMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - !FindInMap 
          - AWSInstanceType2Arch
          - !Ref InstanceType
          - Arch
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update -y
          apt-get install -y python-pip
          apt-get install -y python-setuptools
          mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin
          python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py --script-dir /opt/aws/bin https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --configsets setup --region ${AWS::Region}
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --region ${AWS::Region}

  ApplicationLoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Subnets: !Ref Subnets
  ALBListener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref ALBTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLoadBalancer
      Port: '80'
      Protocol: HTTP
  ALBTargetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 3
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access and HTTP access on the configured port
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
Outputs:
  URL:
    Description: URL of the website
    Value: !Join 
      - ''
      - - 'http://'
        - !GetAtt 
          - ApplicationLoadBalancer
          - DNSName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `cfn-signal` for `LaunchConfiguration` in the following line:

> action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --configsets setup --region ${AWS::Region}

You can signal **only three types of resources** with [CreationPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html), witch are `Instance`, `WaitCondition` and `AutoScalingGroup`.

Thus in your case you should be **signalling your AutoScalingGroup**, not `LaunchConfiguration`.